# Using a private framework (with pods) inside a project's podfile

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I've created a private framework which utilises a number of pods. I want to now use this framework (which has a podspec file) in a project also using Cocoapods.

I've searched for many hours but cannot find a working example. My use case is that I am creating multiple apps, however these apps share a lot of code and assets (storyboards, files, etc). Therefore the framework contains all these common components and needs to be used in each app target.

I currently have this but it does not work as it should:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!
workspace 'Project.xcworkspace'

def shared_pods
  pod 1
  pod 2
  pod 3
end

target 'Target1' do
  shared_pods
end

target 'Target2' do
  shared_pods
end

target 'MyPrivateFramework' do
  project 'MyPrivateFrameworkDirectory/MyPrivateFramework.xcodeproj'
  shared_pods
end

target 'TestsTarget' do
  inherit! :search_paths
  # Pods for testing
end
```

The warning I receive is:

```
[!] The Podfile contains framework targets, for which the Podfile does not contain host targets (targets which embed the framework).
If this project is for doing framework development, you can ignore this message. Otherwise, add a target to the Podfile that embeds these frameworks to make this message go away (e.g. a test target).
```

Answer (score 2):

I found my answer by reading this thread carefully: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6123 and comparing with the sample project here: https://github.com/benasher44/CocoaPodsLibExample